Handling Nested Exceptions in Python
I'm working with custom exceptions in Python and trying to understand how to properly catch them within nested try-except blocks. Here's the code:
When I raise the Unauthenticated exception, I want it to be caught by the final except Exception as e: block. How can I make this happen?
class UserNotFound(Exception):
    ...
    
class Unauthenticated(Exception):
    ...

try:
    raise UserNotFound("failed to get user")
except UserNotFound as e:
    print("tirgger user not found Exception", e)
    raise Unauthenticated("auth failed") from UserNotFound
except Exception as e:
    print("handled errors")

